# Using TS Enum Flags in Angular 2+ template

Tags: angular, enums, angular2-template, flags

In Angular is it possible to use TypeScript's Enum Flags inside the template?
I'm getting a rejection with the "&" bitwise operator.
I suspect it's not possible, just double checking.

```
export enum Flags {
  Virgin  = 0,
  Loading = 1 << 0,
  Loaded  = 1 << 1,
  Hidden  = 1 << 2,
}
// component.ts
  public flags = Flags;
// component.html
  *ngIf="(userDetailsFlags$ | async) & flags.Loaded"
// Error:
Parser Error: Unexpected token &, expected identifier, keyword, or string at
```

**Update:**
To everyone commenting about using "&&" instead of "&", please read [this document first](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/enums.html#enums-as-flags).
I know full well the difference between the two.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using `&&` instead?

Comment: In Angular's `*ngIf` you should pass an `boolean` value in it.  So you can't apply an bitwise operation in this expression.  I think the template engine can't recognized the `&` syntax.

Comment: The confusing seems to be coming from attempting to use a bitwise expression in something that expects logic expression. `&` is not accepted in the template as I mentioned, but you can create a typescript method to both use the bitwise operator and return a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

The correct use of AND within a template is the logic operator double ampersand `&&`. Bitwise isn't available directly in the template.

`*ngIf="(userDetailsFlags$ | async) && flags.Loaded"` should do the trick, but if you want to apply a bitwise you can do so within your component typescript.

Here's the docs directly stating bitwise isn't available in template: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator. `&&` is logical AND.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that. Thanks for catching it.